# Is it possible to exclude objects from cubemap baking EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I want to add dynamic cubemap to car animation with car parented to cubemap. I'm curious if it is possible to remove car from baking with autobake to make occlusion sphere as small as possible.
[image: Its not smallll!!!11]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Visibility Collection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/light_probes/reflection_cubemaps.html):

1. Make a collection with your car and any object you want to exclude.
2. In the cubemap object, add that collection as a visibility collection
3. Tick the invert button to make it behave as an exclusion.

[image: cubemap setup]

Comment: Thank you so much